# Find and classify the critical points of the function $f(x,y) = x^3 +2y^3 - 3x^2 -24y + 6$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have to find and classify the critical points of the function: $$f(x,y) = x^3 +2y^3 - 3x^2 -24y + 6$$

I have said that $$f_x = 3x^2 -6x=0 $$
$$3x(x-2)=0$$
$$x=0, 2$$

$$f_y=6y^2-24=0$$
$$y=±2$$

I don't really know how to link the two x values to the two y values obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of clear-minded critical thinking can go a long way. First of all, I want you to realise that your two-variable function is relatively straightforward since the varibales $x$ and $y$ are not entangled but completely separate.

Now, at any of the four critical points your function will have either a local minimum or a local maximum. So, the ordered pairs (0,2), (0,-2), (2,2), (2,-2) are all critical points of the two-variable function.

Does that make sense or is there still something unclear?

I will let you determine for yourself whether each critical point is a local maximum or a local minimum.

Comment: Very appreciated! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.